# Keep an iOS application running in background forever

Tags: ios, accelerometer, background-process

This question might be duplicate of many others but I am still asking because I really need to get any solution of it.

For iOS versions prior to 6, for devices other than those having an A7 chip.

I have an application which interacts with the Accelerometer. I am also running it in background by playing a sound file and turning the Audio services ON for background task.

Now If any third application plays music, it takes control of shared Audio Session of device which causes my background thread to call completion handler assuming that background task has been completed.

Now my application is interruptible by iOS and iOS can kill it if it remains in background for a long time after which I couldn't interact with accelerometer.

Is there any way/trick/hack to keep my application running all the time until unless I kill it by my own.

Again, this is a duplicate question but I really wanted to share my problem with you people to help me in this sense.

Comment: As I know we can't do it forever.The background app running is the most difficult and unstable concept which I am facing in the iOS.

Comment: Not really a good idea as per [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apple is very clear on this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20):

> Implementing Long-Running Background Tasks
>
> For tasks that require more execution time to implement, you must
>   request specific permissions to run them in the background without
>   their being suspended. In iOS, only specific app types are allowed to
>   run in the background:
>
> Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background,
>   such as a music player app
>
> Apps that record audio content while in the background.
>
> Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as
>   a navigation app
>
> Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
>
> Apps that need to download and process new content regularly
>
> Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories

Collecting accelerometer data is not listed. Therefore, what you are trying to do is not possible. "Ways, tricks, hacks" tend to get discovered quickly and offending apps removed from the App Store.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I have just a little question more expanding out talk on this. iOS kills application after some mins, for my case its almost greater then 3 mins it kills my app and my Background Task Completion handler calls. Now what if I again call the same Background function in the completion handler.